# Excel: time series with markers for events

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have daily data for two stocks for about 10 years, and sometimes there are some specific events (such as an announcements or a political events, not numerical data) I would like to show on my graph.

When I'm plotting the 2 time series I would like to add a cross or a line from the x-axis on the graph when the specified eventS happen.

My data on the Excel sheet are presented as follow: 1st column is the dates, 2nd colum is the value of stock 1, column 3 is the value of stock 2, and last column is the name of the event when there is one otherwise it's written #N/A.

I've tried a few tutorials online but they don't work.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

:)

Comment: A simple workaround: use helper columns/rows to create data for the event--a Y value of 0 and a Y value at the maximum shown on the chart.  Plotting those two points with a connecting line will give you a vertical line at that date on the X axis.  Make each event a separate series, or create a 0, max, 0 sequence so the connecting line returns to the axis between events.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please give me more details how to do it ? With commands etc Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve an effect like this:
[image: Example 1]

1)  Convert your existing data into a Data Table `Insert>Table`.
2)  Add a helper column, called "Event_Helper", with the following formula `=IF([@event]="",na(),0)`.  This returns a 0 value whenever you have a named event in your Event column, otherwise it returns #N/A which is ignored by Excel when charting a series.
3)  Create an XY/Scatter Chart (not a line chart), using

- X Values = Date column
- Y Values = Stock A, Stock B, and Event_Helper columns

4)  Add data labels to your event data series and format to taste.

If you'd like to add vertical lines like this:
[image: Example 2]

5)  Add an additional helper column "Error_Helper" to your table with the following formula:`=IF([@Event]="",NA(),MIN(Table1[@[StockA]:[StockB]]))`.  This returns the minimum and lowest charted stock value when there's a named event, otherwise it returns #N/A.
6)  Add error bars to your Event_Helper data series.
7)  Delete the horizontal error bars.
8)  Format the vertical error bars with a Custom Error Amount, using:

- Positive Error Value = Error_Helper
- Negative Error Value = 0

9)  Format the error bars to taste.